# Adding custom methods to std::vector or typdef

Tags: c++, vector, typedef

So I have the following code that makes it possible to "search" for a string of an object in a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct migObj
{
    migObj(const std::string& a_name, const std::string& a_location) : name(a_name),             location(a_location) {}
    std::string name;
    std::string location;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<migObj> migVec;
    migVec v;
    v.push_back(migObj("fred", "belfast"));
    v.push_back(migObj("ivor", "london"));

    // Search by name.
    const std::string name_to_find = "ivor";
    auto i = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const migObj& obj) { return name_to_find == obj.name;});
    if (i != v.end())
    {
        std::cout << i->name << ", " << i->location << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code below the commecnt "search by name" is responsible for this result. What I want to do is make a method that is either added to the std::vector or to the typedef migVec, so I can call

```
v.myNewSearchFunction("ivor");
```

Comment: You would have to write your own class for this. It doesn't really seem worth the hassle, given that you have a solution that works with minimal code.

Comment: No. You can either write a wrapper around `std::vector` which has this function, or make the function take a reference to a `vector`.

Comment: I think the only way it is possible is through the deplorable practice of inheriting from std::vector (which was not designed to be inherited). You better make it a standalone function.

Comment: @juanchopanza the problem is that this function will be used very often so refer to objects created in the vector which could render the code unreadable. using such a function would make things much easier

Comment: That is a matter of opinion. I don't see how calling a member function is less unreadable than calling a non-member function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do that: C++ doesn't have extension methods similar to what you have in C#.

You could derive your class from vector, but then you have to change all the client code. Besides, as Roddy points out, std::vector doesn't have a virtual destructor, so deriving from it is a bad idea in general.

IMO, writing a simple function would be much better choice. Additional benefit is that it would also work for most other containers (e.g. `std::list`) and be more compatible with most of algorithms in STL which are also typically free functions.

So you would have this instead:

```
myNewSearchFunction(v, "ivor"); // instead of v.myNewSearchFunction("ivor");
```

Internally, this function does `std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), ...`.

BTW, please note that it would be better to use `std::begin(v), std::end(v)` than `v.begin(), v.end()`. This lets you run the same code on e.g. arrays.

Putting things into classes [isn't always the best choice in C++](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).

Comment: Even better: write a new algorithm that takes an iterator range, à la the std library. Then it will immediately work with other containers of `string`s.

Comment: Yes, but what would be the difference from `std::find_if` then? My understanding is that OP wants to avoid repeating `(v.begin(), v.end())` part

Comment: Saves spelling out the lambda every time? Not a lot.

Comment: std::vector doesn't have virtual destructor. Deriving from it is not always a good idea.

Comment: @Roddy I'd actually say "Publicly deriving from it is never a good idea."

Comment: @BoBTFish: I would actually recommend an algorithm working on a sequence than on a pair of iterators, the idea of a pair of iterators was a mistake for 2 reasons: more verbose and *so* easy to screw up (wrong order, iterators from different containers etc...)

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: actually, it's better to use `begin(v)` and `end(v)` after bringing the `std` version in scope with `using` declaration. By letting ADL to pick the correct version, you allow a user to use a custom container (with their own `begin`/`end`) and you just need to bring the `std` version in scope to handle C-arrays.

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible. At least not in any way that is recommendable.

To elaborate a bit: You cannot "extend" C++ classes to have more methods than in their primary definition. In other words, you cannot redefine the class or "reopen" its definition to add more features.

What you should do: Write a free function, taking the vector as first parameter. That is as good as writing a method, has no caveats. The generated assembler would likely be identical to a new method:

```
migVec::const_iterator findByName(migvec const& mv, std::string const& name) {
  return std::find_if(std::cbegin(mv), std::cend(mv), [&](const migObj& obj) { 
    return name == obj.name;
  });
}

//...
auto pos = findByName(v, "ivor");
```

What you could *theoretically* do but shouldn't:

- Derive from `std::vector`. Don't do this. It's not designed to be derived from, and you could run into tons of trouble.
- Specialize `std::vector<migObj>`. It is allowed to provide full specializations of standard library templates. However, you'd have to provide the *complete* definition of the specialized vector, meaning alls its standard methods and the new method you want it to have. To achieve this, you'd either have to practically copy `std::vector`'s defintion from your library header (wich is not portable) or roll your own definition, wich is tedious work. Just don't go there.